# Deleting a specific person messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Now it only delete the "content" last messages:

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, content:int):
            await ctx.message.delete()
            if content > 0:
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=content)
                if content == 1:
                    title = f'Usunięto {content} wiadomość'
                    colour = discord.Colour.blue()
                else:
                    title = f'Usunięto {content} wiadomości'
                    colour = discord.Colour.blue()
            else:
                title = 'Hej! Wartość nie może być mniejsza od 0!'
                colour = discord.Colour.red()
            clear = discord.Embed(
            title = title,
            colour = colour
            )
            clear.set_author(name=ctx.bot.user.name, icon_url=ctx.bot.user.avatar_url)
            clear.set_footer(text=version)
            textMsg = await ctx.send(embed=clear)
            await textMsg.delete(delay=2)
```

I want to make bot delete only specific person (e.g. "!clear 5 @Thundo#0000 <= mention) - will delete only last five Thundo's messages and it won't delete other messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **check** kwarg of the purge function. It takes in a function with one parameter- the message. You can make that function return True only if the message.author is the one whose messages you're trying to delete. Pass that function to the **check** kwarg. You can also pass the number of messages, that should be deleted, to the **limit** kwarg, as an integer. And boom, that's it

Comment: can you make an example of it?

Comment: It would be spoonfeeding but whatever here you go :D https://i.imgur.com/YCheA8z.png

Comment: also using that code in the pic, make the default value of the member parameter to None, so that if you don't give a member, it won't give an error, but instead default to None, and then as the first lines, you can check if member is None. If it is, purge without using the check.

Comment: okey it works,  but now I have a problem with discord.channel.purge(limit) it looks like e.g. !clear 4 @Thundo - will try to delete last 4 messages if Thundo is author, but if no, it will not - that's true, but the problem is if LAST four messages are not Thundo's it will not delete anything, because there's no Thundo's messages. I want to make the bot try to delete last four thundo's messages anyway even if this messages were sent 3 days ago and other members spam on this channel. Anybody can help with this problem? :-)

Comment: You could use channel.history() and make it search until you count the given amount of that person's messages. And save those in a list every time, and then at the end delete them. Problem with that is, every 100 messages back that it looks up is a call to the discord API. And it's not good if you do a lot of those frequently. They could disable your account for abusing the API. So In a scenario where that person has never sent a message, yet you're looking for a message of theirs in a server with 500,000 messages, you can see how badly this can go xd

Comment: i will add a one time clear limit (1000 messages back)

Comment: one time more - could you give me an example, please? :P

Comment: No, sorry. It's way too complicated for me to invent it right now. Maybe if somebody else would like to. You coooould also look for coding servers on Discord where you can ask for help. Those are very good and there are active people in a lot of them if you find the right ones. I'm sure somebody would give you some sort of an example of it if you keep pushing

Comment: Also thanks for picking my answer as "accepted" :D. It gave me 15 points and unlocked some stuff for my account. Haven't really answered any posts before on this website xd